# Can I approximate a unit vector in $C^d$ with complex algebraic vectors in the unit ball in $C^d$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, analysis

My answer: Let $z=(z_1,.....z_d) \in C^d$ be so that $||z||=1$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. The algebraic complex numbers are dense in $C$. So, for all $i$, find $a_i$, complex algebraic such that $|a_i|<|z_i|....(1)$ and $|a_i-z_i|<(\epsilon)^{1/2}/2^d....(2)$. let $a=(a_1,.....a_d)$
By (1), $||a||<||z||=1$. So, a is in the unit ball. By (2), $||a-z||<\epsilon$.
So, any point on the unit sphere can be approximated by a complex algebraic vector in the unit ball in $C^d$. So, the answer is yes.
Is this proof correct???

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: I am playing around with specific d but am not getting anywhere. I am writing a paper where I need that any unit vector in $C^d$, (for arbitrary d ) can be approximated with a vector in the unit ball in $C^d$ with complex algebraic entries. I just need that such an approximation exists. I don't need to actually construct one

Comment: Isn't the case of the ball easy?  Just approximate each coordinate and then shrink the whole approximating vector slightly, if necessary,  to keep it in the ball. Am I missing something?

Comment: It makes sense geometrically. I will try to formalize it

Comment: fredgoodman- So, your proof essentially shows that vectors with rational co-ordinates are dense in the closed unit ball. right?

Comment: @fredgoodman. I posted my answer which is a formalization of your idea. Is this what you had in mind? Is the proof correct?

Answer (score 2):

Let $(z_0, \dots, z_n)\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|^2 = |z_0|^2 + \cdots + |z_n|^2 = 1$. Choose algebraic $w_0, w_1, \dots, w_n\in \mathbb{C}$ close to the respective $z_i$, and assume without loss of generality that $w_0\not = 0$ and that $r = 0 < |w_1|^2 + \cdots + |w_n|^2 \leq 1$. Then $w'_0 = (1 - r^2)^{1/2} |w_0|^{-1} w_0$ is also algebraic, and $w' = (w'_0, w_1 \dots, w_n)$ has $|w'|^2 = 1$.

(The only potential snag in making this argument more precise is the case $w_0 = 0$, which you can deal with either by treating that case separately or by induction. What makes this argument work is that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\subset \mathbb{C}$ is closed under taking square roots, whereas $\mathbb{Q}$ itself is not.)

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I am trying to check why $w_0$ is close to $w_0^{'}$, which we need for $w$ to be close to $w'$.

Comment: we also need $w_0$ is close to $w_0^{'}$ for $w'$ to be close to $(z_0,....z_n)$. Here, $w_{0}'-w_{0} \leq ((1+r^2)^{1/2}-1)$, which is not necessarily small?

Comment: Since $|z_0|^2 = 1 - |z_1|^2 - \cdots - |z_n|^2 \approx 1 - r^2$, the quantity $(1 - r^2)^{1/2}/|w_0|$ is close to $1$. (Away from $z_0 = 0$, at least, but that's an easy case to handle.)

Comment: Your proof shows that the complex algebraic vectors are dense in the unit sphere in $C^d$. A simpler question is: Can complex algebraic vectors in the unit ball be used to approximate arbitrary vectors in the unit sphere? Is my proof (posted) about the simpler question correct?

Comment: Ah, you edited the question in the interim. Yes, your proof is fine; you can even take the points over $\mathbb{Q}$ without any changes.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, $Q$ works as well